# "Recommend you to" vs. "recommend that you"

Tags: grammaticality, differences

> I recommend you to define those parameters beforehand.
>   I recommend that you define those parameters beforehand.

Are both sentences grammatically correct? If yes, do they mean the same thing? If yes, which one should I use?

Comment: Is "recommend you to" possibly British English? It is incorrect in American English.

Comment: The third option is 'recommend' + [nominal clause] — "I recommend takING supplements in the wintertime." —this is the best option, in my opinion.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following variant is correct:

> I recommend that you define those parameters beforehand.

You can also omit the word *that*, giving the following:

> I recommend you define those parameters beforehand.

However, the variant with *to* is incorrect. The verb *recommend* always takes either a noun object or a subordinate clause as a complement, never an infinitive.

Answer (score 17):

Actually I believe that both variants can be technically correct, but they are saying very different things, and using the "you to" variant is mostly done as a mistake where "that you" would have been correct.

> **I recommend that you define those parameters beforehand** -> my recommendation (to you) is that those parameters should be defined beforehand.
>
> **I recommend you to define those parameters beforehand** -> my recommendation (to some other currently unspecified person) is that you are the person best-suited to the task of defining those parameters beforehand.

Comment: Hellion, pls reply to lenks' Oxford example.

Comment: @Hellion So, when we talk about someone in general and not somebody in particular, we can say 'I recommend them/you/a writer/ a teacher, etc. to do sth'. Did I get you right?

Comment: Please add substantiating references. Note that OALD gives the 'advise' usage: 'We'd recommend you to book your flight early.' As @lenks points out.

Answer (score 2):

I think both are correct:

https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/recommend

> recommend somebody to do something
>   We'd recommend you to book your flight early.

Comment: Could you expand what you are saying with examples and explanations. That's kind of the point english.se

Comment: very good. I always have questions about that. Contrary to Hellion's answer. Surprised to see that Oxford has an example of "recommend xx to do xxx".

Comment: @lenks This is contrary to what is written in the Longman Dictionary:
✗Don’t say: I recommend her to speak to a lawyer.
https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/recommend

Comment: I would say that the reason "(would/should) recommend" is possible with an 'infinitive'-to clause is that we have modality/conditional in place of the subjunctive mood.  "I should certainly recommend you to return to your practice."  
 (- Sherlock Holmes to Watson, in "The Final Problem") —emphasising the recommendation, while using a 'gerund' (nominal clause) emphasises the action (rather than the recommendation itself).

Answer (score 1):

"I recommend you to define" is **not** correct, because the noun immediately following "recommend" is the direct object in standard usage.    The example creates cognitive dissonance, because the syntax does not match the semantics:    "to define" is the recommendation (or direct object), and "you" is the indirect object.

Oxford's example does not contradict this; "recommend somebody to do something" means that "somebody" is the recommendation, like in "I recommend John for the job."

I hear and see this non-standard usage many times a day in (Indian English and) the English of non-native speakers from various Asian and European countries -- and it drives me **crazy**!   LOL

Comment: It also always bothered me (admittedly more so when 'foreigners' use it) until I read Sherlock Holmes talking to Watson, in "The Final Problem": "I should certainly recommend you to return to your practice."