# recommend you to try or recomend you to trying?

Tags: grammar

Should it be:

> I highly recommend you **to try tea** with ginger and squeezed lemon
>   or
>
> I highly recommend you **to trying tea** with ginger and squeezed lemon

Comment: *The plumber **recommended buying** a new water heater.
The plumber **recommended me to buy** a new water heater. (I was **recommended to buy** a new water heater.) (the to-infinitive after recommend is less common in everyday contexts).*  https://www.grammaring.com/to-infinitive-or-gerund-advise-recommend-allow-permit-forbid-require

Comment: I am confused. What is the correct answer then?

Comment: 1) I highly ***recommend you to try*** tea with ginger and squeezed lemon or

2) I highly ***recommend  trying***  tea with ginger and squeezed lemon

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Recommend you to" vs. "recommend that you"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/35953/recommend-you-to-vs-recommend-that-you). [OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/recommend) has a good range of different examples of the correct uses of 'recommend'. I recommend trying it. I recommend you to try it.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - not really a duplicate. The issue here is to+gerund vs to+infinitive after recommend.

Comment: The second example is unidiomatic (at best) and, while the first is not totally unacceptable, it is on the way to obsolete via archaic. It 'should be' 'I highly recommend that you try tea with ginger and squeezed lemon' or, probably most idiomatic, 'Have you tried ginger and squeezed lemon!?' (tyhe recommendation being implicit in the tone of delivery).

Comment: @Hachi No; OP has a 'you' in between. But this is covered in depth at the other thread. And OALD, for instance (link at duplicate) gives 'He recommended reading the book before seeing the movie' as an example of recommend + ing-form.

Comment: *I highly recommend you to try* sounds like an old-fashioned way of saying it. *I highly recommend you try* or *I highly recommend trying* would be more modern ways of phrasing this. [Evidence from Ngrams for this](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=recommend+you+to+read%2Crecommend+you+read%2Crecommend+that+you+read%2Crecommend+reading&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crecommend%20you%20to%20read%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crecommend%20you%20read%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crecommend%20that%20you%20read%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crecommend%20reading%3B%2Cc0).

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence..
"I highly recommend you to try tea with ginger and squeezed lemon or"
Is correct.
Saying, "I would recommend that you try it," is correct but a bit formal.